# Getting plots from R to powerpoint

Tags: r

I use "ggplot2" to create beautiful plots in R. I want to distribute them; I use "ReporteRs" get them into PowerPoint.

When I do this the formatting is somehow lost (no scale ability). To keep scaleability, I use the "svglite" package to save my plot as a ".svg" file.

Now; How do I get the ".svg" file into the PowerPoint?

Comment: powerpoint does not support svg as vector files (source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/file-formats-that-are-supported-in-powerpoint-252c6fa0-a4bc-41be-ac82-b77c9773f9dc). You need to convert them to a format supported by powerpoint such as EMF. 
Another option is to produce .png files with a high resolution since you will not have to increase their size within ppt.

Comment: Does it have to be powerpoint? You can create beamer presentations using Rmarkdown and knitr, which results in a PDF file containing the presentation slides. With Rmarkdown/knitr, you can also create HTML presentations that can be displayed in a browser.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/README.html

Comment: goodbye PPT.. the Rmarkdown is superior.. i had no idea ...

Comment: Just added a solution using the new export package to export directly to native Powerpoint format using the correct scale!

Answer (score 3):

I just made a new package, `export`, that is built on top of `officer`, and which retains the correct scale by using an appropriately sized Powerpoint slide template, see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html and for demo
https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export

Typical syntax is very easy, e.g.:

```
install.packages("export")
library(export)
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, data = iris, color = Species, 
      size = Petal.Width, alpha = I(0.7))     
graph2ppt(file="ggplot2_plot.pptx", width=6, height=5)
```

Output is vector format and so fully editable after you ungroup your graph in Powerpoint. You can also use it to export to Word, Excel, Latex or HTML and you can also use it to export statistical output of various R stats objects.

Comment: Any hope of making "export" available for R 4.0?

Comment: @DanielYudkin The github version works with R 4.0, https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export. I tried to upload it to CRAN, but there was one check (only with Debian, which I don't have, and I can't reproduce the problem in Ubuntu) that didn't pass, and for that reason they rejected it: * checking for detritus in the temp directory ... NOTE
Found the following files/directories:
  ‘calibre_4.99.7_tmp__pil646u’ ‘calibre_4.99.7_tmp__z831wj6’
If you would happen to know where that problem is coming from let me know...

Comment: @DanielYudkin Export is back up on CRAN now for the latest R version: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Just an update also with regard to support for SVG in Powerpoint: SVG is fully supported in Office 2019 as well as in the Office 365 versions of PowerPoint 2016.

Regarding `rmarkdown/knitr` - you can also use that to [export to Powerpoint](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-Presentations-with-RStudio).

And there is also the option to use my [`export`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html) package, to export to Powerpoint using the correct scaling (specified width & height), as mentioned in my other answer.

Finally, there is also the possibility to export to SVG, and to use e.g. Inkscape to have it converted to EMF, which you can import in all versions of Powerpoint.

Answer (score 0):

With [ggplot::ggsave](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsave.html), save the plot to .svg or .eps to include a scalable form  in the powerpoint.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point()
ggsave("mtcars.svg")
ggsave("mtcars.eps")
```